# Ng-bootstrap Carousel missing sliding effect

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Wondering if anyone had luck with it yet,

I am using https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples#config with my ng-9 and bootstrap4.4 project. works well but doesn't have sliding animation\effect.

Couldn't find a working example anywhere.

Thanks for taking out time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is not implemented by the ng-bootstrap team yet, I have opened the bug @https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/3718

In the meantime, if anyone looking for a solution, this works well: [Customise NG Bootstrap carousel in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131765/customise-ng-bootstrap-carousel-in-angular/57134727)

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

ng-bootstrap animation is not implemented yet. It is work in progress: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pull/2817

Comment: Yeah looks like it's incomplete I posted a bug last night: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/3718